# Using bash, how can i find out the average, max and min from a list of numbers?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line-interface

I have a series piped greps, awks and seds which produce a list of numbers, one on each line. Something like this:

```
1.13
3.59 
1.23
```

How can i pipe this to something which will output the average, max, and min?

Comment: If you're piping grep, awk and sed together, the same thing can often be done in one invocation of awk.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[Since you're already using awk](http://blog.damiles.com/?p=33)

```
blahblahblah | awk '{if(min==""){min=max=$1}; if($1>max) {max=$1}; if($1<min) {min=$1}; total+=$1; count+=1} END {print total/count, max, min}'
```

Comment: Nice, it works for me!

Comment: I thought there would of been already a binary which accepts a list of numbers and the count, avg, min, max for you, kind of like using 'time'.

Comment: I would just put the above `awk` pattern in `/usr/local/bin/stats` or such, and then use it as `blabla | stats`.

Answer (score 4):

I find this program useful for generating stats on lists of numbers at the command line: http://web.cs.wpi.edu/~claypool/misc/stats/stats.html

Answer (score 0):

There is also simple-r, which can do almost everything that R can, but with less keystrokes:

https://code.google.com/p/simple-r/

To calculate average, max, and min, one would have to type one of:

```
r summary file.txt
r summary - < file.txt
cat file.txt | r summary -
```

Answer (score 0):

With a tip of the hat to @DerfK:

`perl -lane '$n=$F[0]; if(not defined $min){$min=$max=$n}; if($n>$max){$max=$n}; if($n<$min){$min=$n}; $total+=$n; $count+=1; END{print $total/$count." $max $min"}'`

`$F[0]` is the value in the first (0'th) field of each line

If your input data is comma separated, add the `-F,` modifier before `-lane`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ministat`](https://github.com/thorduri/ministat):

```
$ ministat -n
1.13
3.59 
1.23

x <stdin>
    N           Min           Max        Median           Avg        Stddev
x   3          1.13          3.59          1.23     1.9833333     1.3923122
```

And with `tail`, `sed` and `cut` you can extract a single field, e.g. `ministat -n | tail -1 | sed -r 's/ +/ /g;' | cut -d\  -f 6` gives you the average (since it: takes the last line; removes extra spaces; then takes the sixth non-space token on the line).